# Find the minimum value of a function with additional condition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the minimum value of a function $f(x,y) = x^{2} + 4y^{2} - 4xy + 3x - y + 6$ if $x+y=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know $y=1-x$, which we substitute into $$f(x,y) = x^{2} + 4y^{2} - 4xy + 3x - y + 6$$ to give
\begin{align*}
f(x,1-x) &= x^{2} + 4(1-x)^{2} - 4x(1-x) + 3x - (1-x) + 6 \\
 &= 9x^2-8x+9.
\end{align*}
Now we can find the minimum using the usual methods for quadratics.

Comment: So easy, huh. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this were an intermediate Calculus problem, could use Lagrange multipliers, since x+y-1=0, if

$$F(x,y,t)=x^2+4y^2−4xy+3x−y+6+t(x+y-1)$$
$$F_x=2x-4y+3+t=0$$
$$F_y=8y-4x-1+t=0$$

Subtract to eliminate t:

$$6x-12y+4=0$$
Given $$6x+6y-6=0$$ so
$$18y-10=0$$

$$y=\frac{5}{9}$$
$$x=\frac{4}{9}$$

Comment: I think that Lagrange multiplier isn't the way to go here. It provides the exact solution, but it's more complicated, just use the much simplier substitution like Rebecca

Comment: Both methods give exact solution, Rebecca's solves the particular problem, mine the general problem posed in the title.

Comment: That's what I say. Lagrange Multiplier will evetualy provide the exact solution, but in a much more complicated way. Usually optimization problems with two variables are solved using Rebecca's way.

Comment: @JohnCosi I won't say that your method solves the general problem, as you are making assumptions about differentiability.